# Ambiguous ANTLR parser rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a very simple example text which I want to parse with ANTLR, and yet I'm getting wrong results due to ambiguous definition of the rule.

Here is the grammar:

```
grammar SimpleExampleGrammar;

prog : event EOF;

event : DEFINE EVT_HEADER eventName=eventNameRule;

eventNameRule : DIGIT+;

DEFINE : '#define';

EVT_HEADER : 'EVT_';

DIGIT                   :           [0-9a-zA-Z_];

WS     :   ('' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

First text example:

```
#define EVT_EX1
```

Second text example:

```
#define EVT_EX1
#define EVT_EX2
```

So, the first example is parsed correctly.

[image]

However, the second example doesn't work, as the eventNameRule matches the next "#define ..." and the parse tree is incorrect

[image]

Appreciate any help to change the grammar to parse this correctly.

Thanks,
Busi

Comment: How are you generating the graphs? The second example isn't valid according to your grammar, as `prog` is only a single `event`.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank for your comment.
I use AntlWorks2 to generate the graphs.
http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the missing loop specifier you also have a problem in your WS rule. The first alt matches anything. Remove that. And, btw, give your DIGIT rule a different name. It matches more than just digits.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian pointed out, my main mistake here is that in the initial rule (prog) I used "event" and not "event+" this will solve the issue.

Thanks Adrian.

Comment: Still, even with a missing loop it should not match the second #define because the hash symbol is not part of the DIGIT rule. Maybe the tree printout is buggy?

Comment: thanks Mike. Please note he didn't match the '#define', the red part means unexpected input.